# Running Powershell from C# gives error: `running scripts is disabled on this system`

Tags: c#, powershell

In my C# application, I try to create a `RunSpace` to invoke some Powershell scripts. However when it reaches the code to actually create it, it fails with the error below:

```
var implementedHost = new implementedPSHost();
using (var rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(customPSHost))
{
```

`cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.At line:1 char:3+ . .\Scripts\loadFunctions.ps1+`

As suggested elsewhere, I ran a Powershell window and executed `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` but this did not help. The error still happens. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Is the C# application running in the security context of the same user?

Comment: @RohinSidharth how can I confirm that?

Comment: Can you share the complete code you're using, the error isn't truly generating on the `using` statement, but rather when you attempt to launch a script, we need to see the full body to see what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

Try running your `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser` step within the runspace, like this.

First, with my ExecutionPolicy for this user to Restricted, and I see the following error when i run this code:

```
RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

            using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration))
            {
                runspace.Open();
                RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
                //scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser ");
                Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                Command scriptCommand = new Command("C:\\temp\\test.ps1");
                Collection<CommandParameter> commandParameters = new Collection<CommandParameter>();

                pipeline.Commands.Add(scriptCommand);
                Collection<PSObject> psObjects;
                psObjects = pipeline.Invoke();
            }


 RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
 scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
```

Gives me

> System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException: 'File C:\temp\test.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.'

Next, I rerun it, uncommenting this line:

```
scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser ");
```

And, no errors!  However, this **will change the users ExecutionPolicy**, which I think is bad behavior, so I'm going to instead wrap my function with this and set the Users ExecutionPolicy back the way I found it.

```
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration))
            {
                runspace.Open();
                RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
                scriptInvoker.Invoke("$ExecutionPolicy = Get-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser");
                scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser ");
                Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                Command scriptCommand = new Command("C:\\temp\\test.ps1");
                Collection<CommandParameter> commandParameters = new Collection<CommandParameter>();

                pipeline.Commands.Add(scriptCommand);
                Collection<PSObject> psObjects;
                psObjects = pipeline.Invoke();
                scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser $ExecutionPolicy -Force");
            }
```

Now our function works and we don't tamper with the user's system settings.

Comment: where do I get `RunspaceInvoke` from? Visual Studio is complaining that it doesn't exist

Comment: Add a reference to `System.Management.Automation.dll` which will be found here 

 `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0\System.Management.Automation.dll`

Comment: Yes I already have `using System.Management.Automation` as I was already using `Runspace` etc

Comment: RunspaceInvoke is a member of System.Management.dll, if you've added the reference, be sure to also add it to your usings at the top of your `.cs` file too :) 
`using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaceinvoke?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0

Comment: I did. I'm using version `6.2.1.`. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: 6.2 doesn't expose `RunspaceInvoke` at the present time.  I just checked and PowerShell Core 7 does expose it though, maybe download the preview and try it?  For now, if you used the PowerShell 5 version of `System.Management.Automation.dll` you would also be fine.

Comment: Ok thanks for confirming that. It seems pretty bizarre that they would get rid of this. Ok will add Powershell Core

Comment: Just checked with the newest PowerShell Core Preview and RunspaceInvoke and other members aren't there yet.  I recommend you paste your whole code so that we can try to help.

Comment: There's nothing additional to post though, it's just that when I try to add the line with `RunspaceInvoke` it complains that it doesn't know what it is

Comment: thats a great solution.. should be accepted